# Ruby csv file related operations

Tags: ruby

I'm working on a file related task..I have a CSV file with some rows and headers..I need to fetch column with particular header and create a new column at the end and do some operations..how can i fetch column values which is having particular header value and how can i create new column in the end?

Comment: Doesn't it use `[]` for column access by header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have CSV in following format

Zipcode Network ID  Network Name  Zone  New Network?  Display Name
64024 275 Kansas City 2 No  Kansas City
64034 275 Kansas City 2 No  Kansas City

You can user FasterCSV;
If you have headers in your csv then you can specify it `headers => true` what you can do is to fetch data from row by row using FasterCSV,as given below

```
FasterCSV.foreach(path_to_file, { :headers => true, :row_sep => :auto }) do |row|
```

Each time you iterate the csv you would get row from your CSV file, now you already know that column 2 has "network_id" header and column 3 has "network name" header so you can easily give `network_id = row[2]`, `network_name = row[3]`

hope it would answer your question

Answer (score 0):

First record in CSV may be considered as Header record. There is no rule which dictates that this has to be the case.

Coming to your question. Short answer is that you have to write the logic (using API or without it) to fetch what you consider a "header".

> I need to fetch column with particular header and create a new column at the end and do some operations

I don't think API would provide any implicit mechanism to fetch a particular header. AFAIK CSV does not have a spec. You could use FasterCSV like API to parse through the CSV to get the work done.

Comment: I am using FasterCSV but don knw how to fetch a particular column data...can you please guide me?